# getting an absolute path from xpath selectors

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible for an xpath selection to return the absolute path for each node found?

for quick example

```
//chapter
```

to return

```
//book[1]/chapter
//book[2]/chapter
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Depends a great deal on the implementation. What language are you using? Python, Javascript, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No easy way to do so just using XPath. If you are using XSLT, there are several recipes available, for instance http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6077.html#d7984e96.

Comment: Have taken a look at that link you've provided and it looks very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pythons lxml module can do it by calling an Elements' **getpath** method.